# Getting Blank response when i am executing my curl php with request with wsdl and endpoint url

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

Please help me, getting Blank response when i am executing my curl php with request and wsdl ,endpoint url.

Here is my code:

```
//end point url      
$e_url="https://tmcrmportal.inservices.tatamotors.com/home/B2C/com.eibus.web.soa
        p.Gateway.wcp?organization=o=B2C;cn=cordys,cn=cbop,o=tatamotors.com";

//wsdl
$wsdl="WSDL";

//$curl = curl_init($e_url);
//request
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP=\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\">
<SOAP:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=\\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\\">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse=\\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\\">
<wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>pwd</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</SOAP:Header>
<SOAP:Body>
<samlp:Request IssueInstant=\\"2004-12-05T09:21:59Z\\" MajorVersion=\\"1\\" MinorVersion=\\"1\\" RequestID=\\"456789\\" xmlns:samlp=\\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:protocol\\">
<samlp:AuthenticationQuery>
<saml:Subject xmlns:saml=\\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion\\">
<saml:NameIdentifier Format=\\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified\\">username</saml:NameIdentifier>
</saml:Subject>
</samlp:AuthenticationQuery>
</samlp:Request>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>';




       $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "Accept: text/xml",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Pragma: no-cache",
            "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
            "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
        );


        $ch = curl_init("ENDPOINTURL");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wsdl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    print $err;
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print $response.'Operation completed without any errors';
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `curl`? If you're connecting to a SOAP API, you will find it much easier if use the PHP `SoapClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you're actually getting 500 error, but error output was disabled in your php configuration. If so, check in your phpinfo() that you have curl module installed. Please avoid showing your real credentials when asking a question for security reasons.

Comment: thank you for the reply , its enabled already still else part executing but no response,

Comment: Also please let me know any other way to do this operation

Comment: you have an if condition in the end with print in every case. so i see only 3 cases:
1) $err is empty in if condition
2) error 500 before condition block
3) there is no limit on curl execution, so you still not reach condition block